# ENUM and array declaration using enum to create an array of objects

Tags: arrays, enums, arduino-c++, neopixel

I am writing a wrapper for neopixel library. I am adding a full source code of my program:

I have created my own custom function toggle_led_strip which is using a function from the neopixelbus led strip library.

```
#include "NeoPixelBus.h"
#include <Adafruit_I2CDevice.h>
#define PixelCount  8 // this example assumes 4 pixels, making it smaller will cause a failure
#define PixelPin  27  // make sure to set this to the correct pin, ignored for Esp8266
#define colorSaturation 250

RgbColor blue(0,0,255);
RgbColor black(0);

NeoPixelBus<NeoGrbFeature, NeoEsp32Rmt0800KbpsMethod> strip(PixelCount, PixelPin);


void toggle_led_strip(RgbColor colour){
        strip.SetPixelColor(0, colour);
        strip.Show();
        delay(100);
        strip.SetPixelColor(0, black);
        strip.Show();
        delay(100);
}

void setup() {
  strip.Begin();

  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  toggle_led_strip(blue);
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

Normally, when I want to create a colour variable, I must create it in such way:

```
RgbColor blue(0,0,255);
RgbColor black(0);
```

However, I am learning about different ways of creating colour objects and someone has suggested me to use ENUM and array method as such:

```
enum COLORS
{
blue,black
};

RgbColor a_color[2] = {
  [blue] = {0,0,255},
  [black] ={0}
};
```

From what I understand, the code above will set the first variable of enum (blue) to the {0,0,255} and the second variable of enum (black) to {0} so the result should be exactly the same as if I have used

```
RgbColor blue(0,0,255);
RgbColor black(0);
```

is that correct understanding?

Then I try to pass the color to the function as following:

```
//void toggle_led_strip(RgbColor colour) This is function prototype
toggle_led_strip(blue)
```

But it does not work when using enum and array method and works perfectly with the first method

Comment: Please note that arduino code is not C. `RgbColor blue(0,0,255);` that for example is not valid C. There is an arduino-C++ tag that you can use.

Comment: Is your code really in C? It looks like C++ to me.

Comment: I program on Arduino IDE. The code is arduino c++ as kaylum suggested. I have added a new tag. thanks for spotting

Answer (score 0):

Those who are interested in the solution:

```
void toggle_led_strip(COLORS colour){
        strip.SetPixelColor(0, a_color[colour]);
        strip.Show();
        delay(100);
        strip.SetPixelColor(0, a_color[black]);
        strip.Show();
        delay(100);
}
```

It turned out to be quite simple once you understand that an ENUM is treated as an array index and nothing else. It works as expected now.